# Firestore Data Modeling - Chatbot Dialogflow

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy desarrollando una plataforma que involucra DialogFlow (CHATBOTS) con distintos tipos de integraciones (Whatsapp, Facebook, twitter, etc).

Eso esta resuelto, ya que tiene su propio ecosistema.

El problema, es que necesito modelar en firestore para almacenar las interacciones de los usuarios con el BOT.

Cuando un usuario comienza una interaccion, esta permanece en toda la conversacion a traves de un atributo SESSION.

la data que obtengo es:
userSay,
agentResponse,
agentResponseId,
intentDisplayName,
intentId,
createdAt,
session,
platform.

Con alguna variacion o atributo extra dependiendo de la plataforma de donde viene (WhatsApp, Facebook, Telegram, etc)

El almacenamiento de estos registros es meramente a modo de consulta y reportes, para ofrecen información cuantiosa a quien use la plataforma.

Me encantaría que puedan guiarme, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer si estas usando Firestore es guardar en una coleccion Session todos los chats como pushs independientes, y dentro de cada push independiente usarlo como el chat en el momento.

Por ejemplo

```
    String id = db.collection("session").document().getId();
    db.collection("session").document(id).set(chatMap);
```

`chatMap` seria un `Map` de objetos de tipo `Chat` , donde `Chat` tiene todos tus atributos (serSay, agentResponse, agentResponseId, intentDisplayName, intentId, createdAt, session, platform).

En el codigo podemos ver tambien que creamos primero el id aleatorio para el documento y despues lo seteamos en Firestore con sus datos del chat, de esta forma ya sabemos el id en el momento que esta ocurriendo esa sesion y podemos actualizar sus valores dentro del documento.

A la hora de abrir otra session distinta, vas a abrir otra id distinta en session para ese chat.

Para consultar los chats, solo recorres toda la colección session y obtienes cada valor

Comment: Excelente! seguí tu consejo y la verdad que fue una excelente alternativa para contemplar lo que quería hacer.